# Use orientation detection to determine position of an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a header(h1) on a HTML page where a title is centered. 
The portrait mode lets an image be above that title, and I want the image to be on the left side of the Title when changing orientation to landscape.

I've tried with `<br>` combining with @media screen and `(orientation:portrait/landscape)` 
and different settings without any progress. If I use float left the image still stay on the line above the Title etc. I really have no clue how to solve it..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1><img>"picture"</img><br>Car</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: fiddle or your code will be helpful

Comment: It's basically just for testing.
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>
<h1><img>#</img><br>Car</h1> 
</body>
</html>`

@Mr.Alien
Let say that's for portrait mode, I want to bring the img beside the header "Car" on it's left side. The h1 is centered with css. Using @media screen and (orientation:portrait) I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code will help you.

**html Code**

```
<h1><img src="img.jpg" /> <span>Call</span></h1>
```

**Css Code for Normal View**

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
h1 img{
    display:inline;
}
h1 span{
    display:block;
}
```

**Css Code for landscape View**

```
h1 span{
    display:inline;
    background-color:#3CF;
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
}
```

adjust the top position according to your image height.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did the same thing! block and inline to get the effect.